# compare set with map

Tags: apex

I am having one Map and its giving output like this

```
Map<String, String> staffStatus = new Map<String, String>();

Output : {0030p00000C9cKgAAJ=Draft}
```

and one set

```
Set<Id> setstaffID=new Set<ID>();   

Output :{0030p00000C9cKgAAJ, 0030p00000C9dD3AAJ}
```

And I tried like

```
Boolean blnAllStaffPresent=false;
  for(string  staff :  setstaffID)
  {
      if(staffStatus.containsKey(staff) && staffStatus.get(staff)=='Completed')
      {
        blnAllStaffPresent=true;
      }

  }
```

I have to iterate over the set and have to finally set a boolean variable as true only if the below condition satisfies

All the set keys have to be present in Map and all the keyset values in Map has to be as "Completed".If it is draft then final boolean variable has to be false.

Is there any easy approach for this.

Please help me with easy logic

Comment: Please [edit] this post to show us *what you're tried* and *where you're stuck*. As a reminder, providing code or logic for requirements is not a goal of this community; please see [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: My Bad. I tried like below and not getting desired output  ` Boolean blnAllStaffPresent=false;
  for(string  staff :  setstaffID)
  {
      if(staffStatus.containsKey(staff) && staffStatus.get(staff)=='Completed')
      {
        blnAllStaffPresent=true;
      }
     
  }  `

Comment: Please **[edit] your question**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this quite simply with:

```
Boolean allComplete = 
staffStatus.keySet().containsAll(setstaffID) && 
setstaffID.containsAll(staffStatus.keySet()) && 
staffStatus.values().indexOf('Draft') == -1;
```

This code checks to make sure all keys are in the set, all the values in the set are in the map, and no values have the 'Draft' status.

Comment: Thank you . You saved my time. I am just trying with old traditional approach